# Maximo Anywhere 7.6 - Physical Count App - Issue during the Physical Count Update

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere, tivoli

While updating the physical count of an item in the Physical Count app, below error is being thrown. I'm able to update Physical Count from the Maximo portal.

Unable to understand the root cause of this issue.

Could someone please help?

```
[7/28/16 10:49:33:896 UTC] 000053ad SystemOut     O 28 Jul 2016 10:49:33:896 [ERROR] [MAXIMO] [CID-MXOSLC-3849] Processing failed for OSLCINVBALVIEW. The object structure is 1. The primary object is INVBALANCESVIEW. The key is null.BMXAA1840E - Inventory transaction records cannot be inserted directly from here.
[7/28/16 10:49:33:896 UTC] 000053ad SystemOut     O 28 Jul 2016 10:49:33:896 [ERROR] [MAXIMO] [CID-MXOSLC-3849] BMXAA1840E - Inventory transaction records cannot be inserted directly from here.
psdi.util.MXApplicationException: BMXAA1840E - Inventory transaction records cannot be inserted directly from here.
    at psdi.app.inventory.InvTrans.add(InvTrans.java:168)
    at psdi.mbo.MboSet.addAtIndex(MboSet.java:4584)
    at psdi.mbo.MboSet.add(MboSet.java:4493)
    at psdi.app.inventory.InvBalances.adjustPhysicalCount(InvBalances.java:394)
    at psdi.app.inventory.InvBalances.save(InvBalances.java:960)
    at psdi.mbo.MboSet.saveMbos(MboSet.java:7690)
    at psdi.mbo.MboSet.validateTransaction(MboSet.java:7670)
    at psdi.txn.MXTransactionImpl.validateTransaction(MXTransactionImpl.java:375)
    at psdi.txn.MXTransactionImpl.saveTransaction(MXTransactionImpl.java:207)
    at psdi.txn.MXTransactionImpl.save(MXTransactionImpl.java:156)
    at psdi.iface.mos.MosProcessImpl.save(MosProcessImpl.java:2185)
    at psdi.iface.mos.MosProcessImpl.processExternalData(MosProcessImpl.java:352)
    at psdi.iface.mos.MosProcessImpl.processObjectStructureService(MosProcessImpl.java:212)
    at psdi.iface.mic.MicService.processObjectStructureData(MicService.java:2080)
    at psdi.iface.mic.MicService.processOSLC(MicService.java:1728)
    at psdi.iface.mic.MicService.processOSLCJSON(MicService.java:1640)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.maximo.oslc.provider.MaximoOslcProviderServlet.processPostPut(MaximoOslcProviderServlet.java:2037)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.maximo.oslc.provider.MaximoOslcProviderServlet.doPost(MaximoOslcProviderServlet.java:219)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at psdi.webclient.system.filter.HttpXFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(HttpXFrameOptionsFilter.java:38)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at psdi.webclient.system.filter.MTContextFilter.doFilter(MTContextFilter.java:53)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:461)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:528)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:314)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:285)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)
```

Regards,
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

Kartik,
I'm able to perform Physical Count in AW 7.6. (tested using the same ID from Maximo UI and Mobile PC app)
Based on your stack trace, it could be coming from the configuration of INVBALANCESVIEW OSLC. Have you tried to enable logger up to debug?

Comment: Hi Dyka, Thanks for the response. I have enabled the logs and this is the information I have got. Please mention the log settings mentioned by you. I'll double check if they are available or I'll enable and retest the app.